# Impulse response of Linear time-varying system

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory

Suppose we are given the following system:

$
\begin{align*}
\dot{x} &= cos(t)x + \frac{1}{t+1}u \\
y &= sin(t)x 
\end{align*}
$

I'm trying to find the impulse response of this system g(t,$\tau$). My attempt: $\\$

First we need to find the state transition matrix which can ben found by seperation of variables in the first differential equation. This matrix turns out to be:

$\Phi(t,\tau)$ = $e^{sin(t-\tau)}$

\begin{align*}
x(t) = e^{sin(t-t_0)}x(t_0) + \int_{t_0}^{t}e^{sin(t-\tau)}\frac{1}{\tau + 1} u(\tau) d\tau
\end{align*}

when $u(\tau) = \delta(\tau)$ and initial conditions are zero then:

\begin{align*}
g(t,\tau) = sin(t)e^{sin(t)}
\end{align*}

Why this answer does not depend on $\tau$ which we normally expect. Do you spot any mistakes in this attempt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integrating factor is just $e^{-\sin(t)}$. This gives the solution formula
$$
x(t)=e^{\sin(t)-\sin(t_0)}x_0+\int_{t_0}^te^{\sin(t)-\sin(s)}\frac1{1+s}u(s)\,ds.
$$
Now if $u(s)=\delta_\tau(s)=\delta_0(s-\tau)$, then
$$
x(t)=e^{\sin(t)-\sin(t_0)}x_0+\theta(t-τ)e^{\sin(t)-\sin(\tau)}\frac1{1+\tau},
$$
with $θ$ for the Heaviside unit jump function.

Comment: I made a mistake while writing the state transition matrix and forgot about unit step function. Thanks for your time @Lutz Lehmann.